# Imagesetpixel - changing pixel value

Tags: php

I must to create a script that read an image, and encode it changing the pixel value for each channel...

So I open the source JPEG image, and i write each pixel in another image handle.

To encode I do this:

```
$rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
$colors = imagecolorsforindex($img, $rgb);

$rosso = cripta($colors['red'], 100);
$verde = cripta($colors['green'], 100);
$blu = cripta($colors['blue'], 100);
```

Here the "cripta" function:

```
function cripta($valore, $step)
{
    $delta = $valore + $step;

    if($delta > 255)
    {
        $num = $delta - 256;

        return $num;
    }
    else
    {
        return $delta;
    }

}
```

Until here it's all ok...

Here the reverse function:

```
function decripta($valore, $step)
{
    $delta = $valore - $step;

    if($delta < 0)
    {
        $calc = 255 + $delta + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $calc = $delta;
    }

    return $calc;
}
```

When i decode the created image using the same method but with the "decripta" function, some pixel going crazy!

Here some examples:

The source:
http://i61.tinypic.com/2m43ww1.jpg

Decoded image:
http://i60.tinypic.com/wkfngz.jpg

Can somebody help me?

I have this problem only if a save the encode image, and later open it to decode...
If I use the handle without saving, the decoding part it's right!
So why when i save the image, some pixel change the value? I save using:

```
imagejpeg($handle, $filename, 100);
```

Comment: You're going to be working with the source of a file, with anything. There is no 100% guarantee that the files source will be exactly as before, this could be for many reasons. One thing to  check over, is encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Paul, the jpg algorithm will always modify some pixels, even with a 100% quality attribute.

To get 100% pixel precision, you must work with a [lossless image format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression), like PNG or TIFF. Working with [GD or Imagick](http://www.sitepoint.com/imagick-vs-gd/) should be possible with lossless format.

> Edited with  l'L'l comment : PNG should be suitable, and is supported
>   by the GD library

Comment: `PNG` format is lossless, so using `imagepng` is a possibility.